# Deploying mule project on public network

Tags: mule, mule-studio

deployed the mule project in a mule stand alone under our organization domain. I could connect to it from anywhere under the domain through the system and the the Project works fine.
The problem is when i deployed on the public network (or Amazon, ..), i am unable to connect to it.
Does there is any specific settings needed to be done when i deployed outside the organization domain.

Comment: can you share your config and your mule version?

Comment: version: 1.3.2
buildDate: 201212121943

Comment: Are you sure you using Mule 1?

Comment: That is mule 3.3.2 in studio. How about your config?

Comment: <flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="rest.RESTJavaClass"/>
        </jersey:resources></flow>
    <flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="rest.RESTJavaClass2"/>
        </jersey:resources></flow>

Comment: are you deploying to mule 3.4.0 standalone? I so @david dossot answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your HTTP endpoints to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Before in AWS itself i couldnt connect to it, but after binding to 0.0.0.0 i could connect to it "locally" - (localhost from AWS). The Problem is still i couldnt connect from outside the AWS instance. Pls help..

Comment: Is your EC2 security group configured correctly, ie do you allow external traffic on port 9091/TCP?

Comment: Does the mule stand alone config file(settings) matters for this specific problem?

Comment: Hard to see how, if you can connect to it locally it means Mule is running and has successfully bound its HTTP endpoint...